# Does it matter if I found a religion on holy site or Stonehenge?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

I have a city with a holy site and Stongehenge. And since I got a prophet with Stonehenge, it's time to found a religion.

Does it matter in any way if I found it on the holy site or Stonehenge?

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference in whether your prophet is activated on a Holy Site or on Stonehenge, you get the same effects (found a religion, gain a founder and one follower belief, and it becomes the majority belief in the founding city). Use whichever tile is easiest to get to.

The reason Stonehenge allows you to found religions on it is that it's common to build Stonehenge before your first Holy Site to secure an early religion. The effect of the wonder would be strongly diminished if you needed to have a Holy Site in order to benefit from it.

Comment: Makes total sense. I built a holy site to have somewhere to use the prophet :D

Comment: Note, that if you found a religion and then built a Stonehenge, you will get free apostle instead. Also, if you got Great Prophet but didn't use it to found a religion and then built a Stonehenge, you want get any units from building it